# Laravel - comment system

Tags: database, laravel, comments

I am trying to build a comment system for my app, in which I have student courses and lessons. Each course has different lessons and I wish for each lesson to show the different comments left in the comment section. However I am stuck at storing the comment only for lesson with id = 1 and I don't know where is the issue. Have tried several solutions, some of them didn't even work.

I have set the relationships in the modules:

```
class Course extends Model{

    protected $fillable=['name', 'language',  'description', 'semester_id','user_id'];

    public function lesson(){
        return $this->hasMany(Lesson::class,'courses_id');
    }  
}

class Lesson extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['courses_id', 'lesson',  'description'];

    public function course(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
    }  

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    } 

}

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['user_id', 'comment',  'lesson_id'];

    public function lesson(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Lesson::class);
    } 
}
```

For each course I am displaying the corresponding lessons and for each lesson the comments.

CommentsController:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'comment' => 'required|min:5|max:3000'
        ));

        $user_id = Auth::id();

        $lesson = Lesson::find($id);

        $lesson_id = $lesson->id;

        Comment::create([
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'comment' => $request->comment,
                'lesson_id' => $lesson_id
        ]);

        return back();
    }
```

View:

```
        <form id="comments-form" method="POST" action="{{url('/lessons/show/'.$course_id.'/'.$lesson->id.'/comments/'.$lesson_id)}}">

            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div>
                <textarea rows="10" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Comment">
            </div>
        </form>

        <div id="comments-section">
            @foreach($comments as $comment)
                <div class="comment"> 
                    <p><strong>Name:</strong> {{$user_name}}</p>
                    <p><strong>E-mail:</strong> {{$user_email}}</p>
                    <p><strong>Comment:</strong> {{$comment->comment}}</p>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment controller I would print out what the incoming id is, or log it somehow. This will make sure that you are receiving the correct lesson id and that the form you submit the comment on isn't only sending $id=1. If that looks ok then I'm not sure what you need the following code

```
$lesson = Lesson::find($id);
$lesson_id = $lesson->id;
```

You should instead be able to do `$lesson_id = $id;`

Comment: I have printed it out and I am only getting id=1 when at the same time the route shows different id for lesson. Idk where it goes wrong

Comment: Well it's somewhere between your route and your controller. I would check the form that you are using to submit the comment info first.